# PHP strtotime() function

Tags: php, syntax, strtotime, fgets

I have a file with the following lines. I want to identify lines which have timestamps less than a week from now(starting from aug 22 for this example).

```
log3.txt
28-08-2011 10:29:25 A string
29-08-2011 14:29:25 A new string
20-08-2011 14:29:25 Don’t include

php file

if($file = fopen("/opt/apache2/htdocs/log3.txt", "r"))
{
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $contents = fgets($file, 23); // This is supposed to be 22.
        echo $contents; // With 22 it only returns 08-29-2011 14:29:25 P
        if(strtotime($contents) > strtotime("last Monday"))
        {
            $string1 = fgets($file);
            echo "In if $string1";
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            $string1 = fgets($file);
            echo "In else $string1"; //Always goes to else statement.
        }
    }
}
```

The timestamps are created with `date('m-d-Y H:i:s')`.

Why does `fgets` need 23 characters when it's actually 22.

What am I doing wrong here with strtotime?

What is the best way to parse lines with timestamps less than a week ago.

EDIT: Got it to work

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $contents);

if(strtotime($date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')) > strtotime("last Monday"))
```

Use DateTime function with `d-m-Y` format or `m/d/Y`.

Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: yup overlooked that but that's not my main question. My main question is parsing timestamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DateTime::createFromFormat instead. strtotime() may have problems to detect the used format of your date.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s A', $contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

The length parameter of `fgets()` includes the newline character (`\n`), that's why have to pass 22+1 to this paramter.

Using `fread()` would be more appropriate for this case.

For the strtotime:

`strtotime` does not recognizes your date format, so you have to parse it in using an other function. [`strptime`](http://php.net/strptime) can do it:

```
strptime('08-29-2011 10:29:25 AM', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php):

*Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, on a newline (which is included in the return value), or on EOF (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.*

As for the conversation, I'd use [strptime()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strptime.php), as your date format is fixed:

```
if(strptime($contents, 'm-d-Y H:i:s A') > strtotime("last Monday"))
```

If this doesn't help you, please `var_dump()` the two `strtotime()` and post the results.

Comment: Ok takes care of the first question. My main problem is strtotime. Thanks for that input though.

Comment: ah, sorry, overlooked that one. edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are not the right format for `strtotime` to return a `timestamp`:

```
$dt = strtotime("08-29-2011 10:29:25 AM");
var_dump($dt); // false
```

**Update**
But [this works](http://codepad.org/FrSfZPkT) for me:

```
$lm = strtotime('last Monday');
$dt = strtotime('23-08-2011');

if($dt > $lm) {
   echo "In if"; // output for dates earlier than 23-08 
} else {
   echo "In else"; // output for 23-08 and later
}
```

Comment: You are right. It's supposed to be in `28-08-2011` or `08/28/2011`. I fixed that but it's the still the same.

Comment: Yes that works individually. Put the date in another file and use fgets/fread to get the date and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it when `strtotime()` gets thrown under the bus.  It isn't evil.  It has great flexibility, but it can only go so far.

`$contents` just needs to be adjusted so that `strtotime()` understands you are feeding it a European-style datetime.  You don't even need to swap around any digits.

Use:

```
if(strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$contents)) > strtotime("last Monday")){
```

This is a simpler fix than instantiating an new object for each iteration.